# How can I save multiple relations 1:N in cascade on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

How can I save multiple relations 1:N in cascade on Laravel?

E.g this is a brief of my database:

```
bills
 -id
 -name

items
  -id
  -name
  -bill_id

item_members
  -id
  -user_id
  -item_id
```

For saving all items of a bill you can do: $bill->items()->saveMany($items). But how can I save all the item_members of item in cascade? like: $bill->items()->saveMany($items)->saveMany($item_members)?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, I believe they need to be separate actions. This also does not assign the item members to users.

Comment: Oh, ok =/. Thank you.